# Ceiling fan gets voltage but lights do not turn on

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

[image: wiring]I just connected a new ceiling fan with lights and the lights and fan won't turn on. I tried to hunt down the problem and used a non contact voltage detector and the voltage does flow to the wires on the light kit but the lights do not turn on. The switch should be fine, since it's brand new and was working with a different fixture before. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1 - Pictures of the switch wiring and the ceiling wiring would be helpful; 2 - Is there one switch or two? Is the switch a simple toggle or a variable speed/dimmer? 3 - Can you disconnect the fan & lights and temporarily connect a simple light fixture to see if that works?

Comment: The switch is a simple toggle switch, and it is just the one. I also had a simple  light fixture before installing the fan, and it worked.

Comment: Model # of the new fan?

Comment: Chapter Ceiling fan model #10295

Comment: I see a lot of from the black wire copper sticking out of the back of the wire nut.  Are you sure you have a good contact?

Comment: Try just white to white, ground to ground and blue to black. This will test the lights. If they come on, then switch the black and blue to try the fan. If they come on but dim, you have a wiring issue. You non-contact will show voltage present, but not how much. Assuming the original light there had no issues, then your wiring should be fine. Make sure the wires are tight and secure.

Comment: @Jeff Cates Yea, I tried the blue to black but the lights still didn't work. The non voltage meter did go off though. Should I be using a multimeter instead? The original light had no issues.

Comment: Use a multimeter to determine if you are actually getting proper voltage to the wires. Out of curiosity, does this have a remote setup?

Comment: Using the multimeter I found my whole circuit is at 97v, I guess I have to check the wiring and find where the culprit is

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a drop in voltage to the whole circuit (97v instead of 120v). After inspecting the wire run from load center to room wiring, I found that the hot and neutral wiring pig tails were loose and needed to be secured. After adjusting the wiring and testing with a multimeter, I wired the ceiling fan + lights and they started working.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Would you add a few details, so future visitors can benefit from your experience? Thanks.